# Getting office365 task properties

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I am working on Office 365 tasks using ews api in c#. I have successfully accessed most properties of a task but fed up with accessing two properties and their values 1-Repetition, 2-Unit of measure for actualwork and totalwork (can access ActualWork and Total work but not their unit of measures eg. if actualwork is set in hours or minutes? how to get this?). Can anyone help me how to get these properties?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aqDJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Y9U.png)

Answer (score 0):

The unit of measurement is always minutes as documented in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219615(v=exchg.80).aspx . Those UI elements are calculated based on the value in minutes. Eg you can easily test this in the UI try setting it to 480 minutes and you should see the UI change to 1 day once you save it and reopen it. But you need to take into account it working hours (where 480 minutes equal one day and 2400 minutes equal one week (8 hours in a work day and 5 work days in a work week)).